# How to clean all cache data?

Tags: vue.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

Is it possible to use garbage collection `cache.gc()` with *vue-apollo*?

### Is there any way to clean all store cache data?

For example, is it possible to run it inside a lifecycle?

```html
<script>
import { apolloClient } from "@/main";
export default {
 mounted() {
    this.$apollo.cache.gc();
    // or may be this.$apollo.queries.birds.cache.gc();
    // or this.$store.cache.gc();
  },
};
</script>
```

I can not get a list after the first register. I have to refresh it.

Comment: You can always add `fetchPolicy: "network-only"` to your Apollo queries and it will skip the cache.

Comment: I want to cache, but I just need a way to erase it in some cases

Comment: Perhaps this example may help you - https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3490#issuecomment-517981137

Comment: `apolloClient.cache.data.clear();` _?

Comment: Or maybe `await client.clearStore(); await persistor.purge()`

Answer (score 1):

first, init apollo client:

```js
import { ApolloClients } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { createApp, provide, h } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
// other ...

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: from([errorLink, requestInterceptor, authLink, traceLink, httpLink]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        addTypename: false
    })
});

const app = createApp({
    setup() {
        provide(ApolloClients, {
            default: apolloClient
        });
    },
    render: () => h(App)
});

export default apolloClient
```

then, you can clear apollo network cache whenever you want:

```js
import apolloClient from 'xxx.ts'

apolloClient.cache.reset()
```